# How to plot one figure with multiple lines in python using

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line-plot

This should be a very simple question for someone out there. I need a line plot in python where the independent variable (x-axis) is the `Date`. The y-axis is the dependent `Value` data and there will be multiple lines: one line per `Name` which describes the changes in `Value` over time. I'm not sure how to do this other than to use matplotlib.

This is how I have my data organized in `df` which pulled data out of a csv file.

```
Name = df['Name']
Value = df['expected harvest (Value)']
Date = df['Date']
result = pd.concat([Name, Value, Date], axis=1)

>>> result
                       Name                     Value      Date
1                       189                       9.0  11/14/15
2                       191                      10.0  11/14/15
3                       192                       1.0  11/14/15
4                       193                       4.0  11/14/15
...                     ...                       ...       ...
2948                    189                       7.0   2/20/16
2950                    190                       1.0   2/20/16
2952                    191                       3.0   2/20/16
2953                    192                       3.0   2/20/16
2954                    193                       0.0   2/20/16
```

So far I've tried this, but I need to lines to be horizontal instead of vertical and for there to be separate lines for each `Name`. Somehow I am missing how to group the data by `Name` and then plot as separate lines.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x_points = df['Date']
x_points = pd.to_datetime(x_points)
y_points = df['expected harvest (Value)']

p = ax.plot(x_points, y_points, 'b')
ax.set_xlabel('x-points')
ax.set_ylabel('y-points')
ax.set_title('Simple XY point plot')
fig.show()
```

[image: This is the wrong plot and not what I need]

Comment: That does not sound like a question, but as work to do. What have you tried?

Comment: I'll add what I've tried. It did not get anything close to what I wanted.

Comment: Your dataframe is not reproducible

Comment: You can be more specific with: "But this is not the plot that I need". You have several points on the same day, I do not think the plot is very clear. Do not you need to add them a day?

Comment: @vaishaligarg but the data frames are straightforward enough that someone should be able to provide guidance, no?

Comment: @JAG2024 see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @lbellomo Ok. I will edit the question. There will be multiple points on each day (the x-axis goes from 11/14/15 to 2/20/16 in a daily time step) and I would like for lines to connect these points. Each `Name` will get its own line.

Comment: Thanks all for the guidance so far on how to make a better question.

Comment: To plot multiple lines you pass multiple x,y sequences - ```plt.plot(x1,y1,x2,y2,....)```.

Comment: Or call ```plt.plot``` multiple times, each time with the different x,y sequence.

Comment: @lbellomo why did you delete your answer? I was just starting to look at it.

Comment: @JAG2024 I miss a part of the question. A few minutes and I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we create sample data

```
sample_dates = ['1/1/15', '1/2/15', '1/3/15', '1/4/15']
dates = []
for date in sample_dates:
    [dates.append(date) for _ in range(4)]
values = np.random.randint(1, 8, size=15)

names = [1, 2, 3, 4] * 4
```

We remove some in the middle (as in the example data that 190 is not). And we transformed it into a Dataframe:

```
names.pop(6)
dates.pop(6)

x_date = pd.to_datetime(dates)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['names'] = names
df['values'] = values
df['dates'] = x_date
```

Now we walk them by name, and we plot them

```
for i in df.names.unique():
    x = df[df.names==i]['dates']
    y = df[df.names==i]['values']
    plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: example]